# plot ordering/layering julia pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, scatter

I have a subplot that plots a line (x,y) and a particular point (xx,yy). I want to highligh (xx,yy), so I've plotted it with `scatter`. However, even if I order it after the original plot, the new point still shows up behind the original line. How can I fix this? MWE below.

```
x = 1:10
y = 1:10
xx = 5
yy = 5
fig, ax = subplots()
ax[:plot](x,y)
ax[:scatter](xx,yy, color="red", label="h_star", s=100)
legend()
xlabel("x")
ylabel("y")
title("test")
grid("on")
```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. As a side comment, you don't need to do `ax[:plot](x,y)` if there is only one axes and figure in the analysis. Just do `plot(x,y)` and plots will be added to the current axes until you call `subplots()` again. At least that is what I remember from matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change which plots are displayed on top of each other with the argument `zorder`. The matplotlib example shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html) gives a brief explanation:

> The default drawing order for axes is patches, lines, text.  This
>   order is determined by the zorder attribute.  The following defaults
>   are set
>
> ```
> Artist                      Z-order
>
> Patch / PatchCollection      1
>
> Line2D / LineCollection      2
>
> Text                         3
> ```
>
> You can change the order for individual artists by setting the zorder.
>   Any individual plot() call can set a value for the zorder of that
>   particular item.

A full example based on the code in the question, using *python* is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(1,10)
y = range(1,10)
xx = 5
yy = 5
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

# could set zorder very high, say 10, to "make sure" it will be on the top
ax.scatter(xx,yy, color="red", label="h_star", s=100, zorder=3)

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("test")
plt.grid("on")

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: It worked for me in Julia too, thanks! BTW, I've added my edit to the code to your answer above.