# 3d plot ordering/layering in julia with pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, julia

As a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106547/plot-ordering-layering-julia-pyplot) question, how can I specify the order of components in a 3D plot in Julia using PyPlot?

Here's the MWE that produces my issue. `zorder` doesn't seem to work.

```
using PyPlot  ## Julia v0.6.4
n = 100
xx = linspace(0,1,n)
yy = linspace(1,2,n)
xgrid = repeat(xx, outer=[1, n])
ygrid = repeat(yy', outer=[n, 1])
zvals = zeros(n,n)
for i in 1:n
        for j in 1:n
            zvals[i,j] = xx[i] + yy[j]
        end
    end
x = 0.5
y = 1.5
z = 2.0
fig, ax = subplots()
plot_surface(xgrid, ygrid, zvals, color="blue", alpha=0.8, zorder=0)
scatter3D(x, y, z, color="red", s=10, zorder=10, label="point")
legend()
xlabel("x")
ylabel("y")
title("test")
show()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error. xgrid is 100x100 and ygrid 1000x1. Should both be matrices?
Also, consider switching to `Plots.jl` and start using `range()` instead of `linspace()`

Comment: @Bazingaa: I needed the `'` on `yy` to make the dimensions appropriate as @German Barletta mentioned. Re-editing.